# WPF DATagrid printing with group

Tags: wpf, printing, datagrid, grouping

How can i print WPF DataGrid with Group Headers,using Paginator

I set the grouping like this

```
dim  _BindingSrcCollectionView As ComponentModel.ICollectionView
_BindingSrcCollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Dt)
For Each GroupColName As String In GroupingColumns
    _BindingSrcCollectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription(GroupColName))
Next
BindingSrcCollectionView.Refresh()
PART_BASE_DATAGRID.ItemsSource = _BindingSrcCollectionView
```

i can Itrate through collectionView like this

```
For Each row As DataRowView In _BindingSrcCollectionView
```

but not getting group header

I cant use print visual, i want to get page wise print from DataGrid